# Jquery append data to a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ejs

I want to append some data to a div element.I want only append to my choice element.

`$('.comments')[0].append($es);`

This not work.(append to [object object])But this work:(but append to all comments)

`$('.comments').append($es);`
Js is here:

```
var yorumcek=[];
function getcomments(n,t){

yorumcek[n]++;
var yorumcekn=yorumcek[n];
    $.get("/cevapyorumal?w=<%-topic.konusayisi%>&sayfa="+yorumcekn+"&s="+n+1,function(data2, status2){
    var x1;
    var y1;
    var sil1="";
     for(var i=0;data2.yorumlar.length;i++){
     var z2=data2.yorumlar[i].date;
     z2=new Date();
     for(var a=0;a<data2.kullanici.length;a++){
     if(data2.yorumlar[i].yazarno==data2.kullanici[a].uyenumara){
     x1=data2.yorumlar[i].yorumcu;

    <%if(sil){%>{if(<%-sil.uyenumara%>==data2.yorumlar[i].yazarno){sil1="-sil-"}
    if(<%-sil.uyenumara%>!=data2.yorumlar[i].yazarno){sil1=""}
}<%}%>
      if(data2.kullanici[a].resim==""){y1="food.png"};
      if(data2.kullanici[a].resim!=""){y1=data2.kullanici[a].resim}
     var $es = $('<div id="ss"><div id="ss2"><div style="float:left"><a id="profilgoster" href="/profilgoster?w='+data2.yorumlar[i].yazarno+'" style="float:left"><span id="yorum">'+x1+'</span>'+
     '<img src="uploads/'+y1+'"id="ssimg"></img></a></div></div><span id="tarih">'+z2.getDate()+"."+z2.getMonth()+"."+z2.getFullYear()+'</span>'+
     '<a id="sila" href="/yorumsil?w='+data2.yorumlar[i].yazarno+"&s="+data2.yorumlar[i]._id+'">'+sil1+'</a><div id="commentana"><div id="comment"><p id="yorump" style="float:left" >'+data2.yorumlar[i].comment+'</p></div></div></div>');

}
 $('.comments')[0].append($es);

 }

 } 

})
return false;
}
```

Html is here:

```
<span class="yrmcek" onclick="getcomments(<%-i%>,this)" style="color:tomato;display:block;margin-top:10px" >yorumları göster ( <%-cevapyolla[i].yorumlar%> )</span>
<div class="comments" style="display:block" > </div>
```

Comment: Provide your HTML (use [Edit] to add it to your question).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (make sure your `html` is correct):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $es = 'Pritam';
    $('.comments')[0].append($es);
    $es = ' Again';
    $('.comments')[1].append($es);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class = 'comments'>Something</div>
  <div class = 'comments'>Test</div>
</body>
```

Comment: @sefereken You will have to use it on document.ready otherwise it won't work. You need to make sure that the dom is loaded before the jquery script runs.

Comment: @sefereken Can you post the whole html and js code?

Comment: But that is very very big file:)

Comment: @sefereken It should work. Make sure the syntax is correct.

Comment: $('.comments').append($es); works perfectly. 
$('.comments')[0].append($es); works;but dont append data to element append this:[object object]